# How can a user with less than 50 reputation leave a comment on another user's question?

Tags: discussion

As per [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation), a user needs atleast 50 Reputation points in order to leave comments globally on the site - one can always comment on one's own questions and answers and answers to questions one has asked.

This means that a user needs atleast 50 Reputation points to comment on a question posted by another user. So, how can [this unregistered user (PaddyinWales)](https://askubuntu.com/users/123989/paddyinwales) [leave this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195107/ts-files-not-recognised#comment303481_195107)? He/She has just 1 Reputation Point.

[image: Comment Screenshot]

I don't think this should be a bug (although it could be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user placed an answer on the question that was actually a comment. As such a moderator converted their answer to a comment.